# React Native não funcionando

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, react, react-native

Eae galera, blz?

Estou querendo iniciar a fazer aplicativo com react native, já instalei os programas necessário para poder inicia-lo, porém quando eu coloco o comando no cmd "npx react-native run-android" ele fica carregando durante um bom tempo e não me dá nenhuma mensagem na tela do Android ('Bem-vindo ao React Native'), não sei se deve ter algum erro ou algo parecido, já pesquisei a respeito disso mas não encontrei nada.

Abaixo coloquei a foto da minha tela, que fica somente nela e não muda nada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quando você roda o comando "react native run android" ele vai fazer a instalação no seu emulador, pela mensagem do terminal, ele está fazendo o download do Graddle, que é usado para fazer o build do aplicativo. Dependendo de sua máquina ou conexão, pode demorar.

Comment: Provavelmente está demorando por estar baixando o a versão do gradle. Você também pode baixar o gradle pelo Android Studio antes de buildar pelo React Native

Answer (score 2):

Para que você possa realizar o build do seu app é necessário rodar o comando:

```
react-native run-android
```

sem o npx na frente, somente é usado o npx para criar um novo projeto react-native com o comando:

```
npx react-native init nomedoprojeto
```

depois de rodado o comando para o build, execute:

```
react-native start
```

Caso o metro bundler do seu projeto não iniciar automaticamente.